# Stay in the same position after $state.reload();

Tags: angularjs

Every time i reload the page with `$state.reload();` I need my page to refresh to the same old position with `<div id="page">` , but it refreshes to the top of the page.
Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the focus shift to <div id="page"> for every time when the page loads

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bootstrap's **Spyscroll**, which allows you to have navigation that you can scroll to. But concerning your issue I suggest [UI-Scroll](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-scroll/demo/). You may look at "*Preserves the scroll position on refresh*" example.

**UPDATE**:

You can try to use **$anchorScroll** to scroll to a desired tag with a given *id*:

```
$location.hash('someID');
$anchorScroll();
```